# Остановить применение классов в пределах одного родительского элемента

Tags: jquery

Есть код, приведу ниже. При нажатии на `<span class="menu-arrow-mobi top">кнопка</span>` подставляются и удаляются классы изменяющие цвет в дочерних элементах каждого `<li class="menu-item>`. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать, что бы классы изменяющие цвет подставлялись и убирались только в рамках одного `<li class="menu-item>`, именно в котором нажималась `<span class="menu-arrow-mobi top">кнопка</span>`?

```js
$('.top').click(function() {
  $('.top').toggleClass('active');
  $('.menu-dropdown-top').toggleClass('active-top');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}

.active-top {
  color: green;
}

ul ul ul
{
background: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="menu-item>
<a href=" # ">1</a>
<ul class="menu-dropdown-top ">
  <li>2</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
<span class="menu-arrow-mobi top ">кнопка</span>
</li>
<li class="menu-item>
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <ul class="menu-dropdown-top">
      <li>2</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
    <span class="menu-arrow-mobi top">кнопка</span>
    <ul>
  <li class="menu-item>
<a href=" # ">1</a>
<ul class="menu-dropdown-top ">
  <li>2</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
<span class="menu-arrow-mobi top ">кнопка</span>
</li>
<li class="menu-item>
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <ul class="menu-dropdown-top">
      <li>2</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
    <span class="menu-arrow-mobi top">кнопка</span>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item>
    <a href=" # ">1</a>
    <ul class="menu-dropdown-top ">
      <li>2</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
    <span class="menu-arrow-mobi top ">кнопка</span>
  </li>
</ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item>
    <a href=" # ">1</a>
    <ul class="menu-dropdown-top ">
      <li>2</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
    <span class="menu-arrow-mobi top ">кнопка</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то такое нужно?

```js
$('.top').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).prev('ul').toggleClass('active-top');
    $('.top').not(this).removeClass('active');       
    $('.menu-dropdown-top').not($(this).prev('ul')).removeClass('active-top');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}

.active-top {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <ul class="menu-dropdown-top">
            <li>2</li>
            <li>2</li>
        </ul>
        <span class="menu-arrow-mobi top">кнопка</span>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href=" # ">1</a>
        <ul class="menu-dropdown-top ">
            <li>2</li>
            <li>2</li>
        </ul>
        <span class="menu-arrow-mobi top">кнопка</span>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href=" # ">1</a>
        <ul class="menu-dropdown-top">
            <li>2</li>
            <li>2</li>
        </ul>
        <span class="menu-arrow-mobi top ">кнопка</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

или такое?

```js
$('.top').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).closest('.menu-item').toggleClass('active-top');
    
    $('.top').not(this).removeClass('active');
    $('.menu-item').not($(this).closest('.menu-item')).removeClass('active-top');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}

.active-top {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <ul class="menu-dropdown-top">
            <li>2</li>
            <li>2</li>
        </ul>
        <span class="menu-arrow-mobi top">кнопка</span>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href=" # ">1</a>
        <ul class="menu-dropdown-top ">
            <li>2</li>
            <li>2</li>
        </ul>
        <span class="menu-arrow-mobi top">кнопка</span>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href=" # ">1</a>
        <ul class="menu-dropdown-top">
            <li>2</li>
            <li>2</li>
        </ul>
        <span class="menu-arrow-mobi top ">кнопка</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Оба варианта с одинаковым эффектом radio? Есть подозрение, что нужен был эффект checkbox-a, имхо.

Comment: Не совсем то, при повторном нажатии на кнопку цвета остаются, а должны отключаться.

Comment: @АннаМатвеева чуть подправил.  ответ

Comment: Мне очень близок первый ваш пример. Но попробуйте покликать, там класс active-top иногда остается на предыдущем li.

Comment: @АннаМатвеева подправил)

Comment: Не подскажите, как реализовать, если в <ul class="menu-dropdown-top "> будет вставлен еще один <ul class="menu-dropdown-top "> с соответствующей кнопкой? )

Comment: @АннаМатвеева давайте в другом вопросе)

Comment: Посмотрите сюда пожалуйста, я создала. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1251037/%d0%9e%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-toggleclass-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0